# regex to check password consist of Character and Number

Tags: jquery, regex

I need a regex for jquery to check the password is between 8 to 32 character and consist of number and character.

Comment: good..so what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: `/^(?=.{8,32}$)(?=.*[a-z]).*\d/i` (assuming you meant "letter" not "character".)